# java modulus math incorrect for rsa encrypt program

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I was making a program to do simple RSA encryption and decryption, anyways when I put in the equation:

```
for (int index = 0; index < message.length(); index++)
{
  decryptnum[index] =(Math.pow((encryptnum[index]),secondkey))% 55; //to the decrypt array
  System.out.print(decryptnum[index] + " ");
  idecryptnum[index] = (int)(decryptnum[index]);
} //changed to int
```

the result came out wrong. for example. the encrypt number was 23 to the 23rd power and then mod 55. the result came out as 23. it should be 12... I think it is maybe a problem with the bytes. it is already a double though, so I dont know what else to do.

Comment: Hint: It's not strictly necessary to compute 23^23 to know what 23^23 mod 55 is.

Comment: I HIGHLY doubt it's a problem with the bytes. Why not put a breakpoint somewhere in your program and debug through the algorithm to make sure all of the values are coming out as expected?

Comment: 23^23 is, according to my calculator, 20880467999847912034355032910567.  How many digits of precision do you think a double carries?

Comment: This is probably a picnic problem. Try reading more how powers and mods work. Break every calculation into smaller ones and check if the result is what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that using `Math.pow` uses `double`s, and the precision isn't high enough.

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("23").pow(23);
System.out.println("[BI] 23^23 = " + bi);
System.out.println("[BI] 23^23 mod 55 = " + bi.mod(new BigInteger("55")));

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
System.out.println("[d] 23^23 = " + df.format(Math.pow(23, 23)));
System.out.println("[d] 23^23 mod 55 = " + df.format(Math.pow(23, 23) % 55));
```

This prints

```
[BI] 23^23 = 20880467999847912034355032910567
[BI] 23^23 mod 55 = 12
[d] 23^23 = 20880467999847910000000000000000
[d] 23^23 mod 55 = 23
```

This explains the incorrect result. `BigInteger` has the precision necessary for this calculation.

While there are other mathematical tricks you can use to avoid calculating 23^23 (mod 55) directly, these numbers are still low enough that you can use `BigInteger` for the precision to calculate it directly.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that your modulus isn't very big, this function is very handy for performing modular exponentiation:

```
public long modPow(long base, long exponent, long mod) {
    long c = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        c = (c * base) % mod;
    }

    return c;
}
```

It's also faster than BigInteger, since it does not have to manipulate big values.
In case there's some need for the source of information, then here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation